# SQL Server parent child account relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have below table with values as this. The highlighted values are newly added rows. Looking the levels I want to get the parent account for those values.

Eg for CGT losses level1ID = 3 Level2ID = 1 and level3ID = 2 means its parent of LevelDescription"CGT Losses Arising During The Tax Year From Sales of Investments"

Need help in grouping ID

I want output as
[image: AcctDescription parentAcctDescription CGT Losses CGT losses Arising During The Tax Year from sales of investments Less Exempt Indexation Adjustment]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that you need to do a self join. You have not given your table properly (please display as text not image) and I haven't tested, the following should do what you need.

```
SELECT
   c.level4ID account_no,
   p.LevelDescription parent,
   c.LevelDescription child
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM table_name
   WHERE Level4Id <> 0) c
JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM table_name
   WHERE Level4ID = 0 ) p
ON
   c.level1Id=p.level1Id,
   c.level2Id=p.level2Id,
   c.level3Id=p.level3Id
ORDER BY
   c.level4Id;
```